# Wordpress backup import using all-in-one plugin not working

Tags: wordpress, import, plugins, migration, backup

Import 169,7 MB wordpress backup, but not running, if i refresh page but i see error, Does this happen if there is a difference in version?

uninstall mysql db and user then create new db & user installing wordpress

[image: Restoring database image, 0% complete]

Comment: Can you give some more information into your actual issue is it saying the file size is too big, are you running into errors if so what errors? please provide more information

Answer (score 0):

## **Changing the upload limit size takes just 5 steps**

1. Go to Plugin editor from the left menu panel in the admin dashboard.
2. Top right, Choose All-in-one WP Migration from the dropdown and click select.
3. Click on constants.php file.
4. Search for the word `AI1WM_MAX_FILE_SIZE`. Change it’s value, refer below code:

   `define( ‘AI1WM_MAX_FILE_SIZE’, 2 << 28 );`
   To
   `define( ‘AI1WM_MAX_FILE_SIZE’, 536870912 * 5 );`

If you even want more than 3 GB then change value from 536870912 * 5 to 536870912 * 10( or any number).
Don’t forget to update the file.

5. Enjoy the new upload size

If the upload size has not changed go to the .htaccess file in the server root folder and add the below lines.

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 2048M
php_value post_max_size 2048M
php_value memory_limit 512M
php_value max_execution_time 300
php_value max_input_time 300
```